# Duplicate may be duplicate of a question, but not the one it was marked as a dupe of

Tags: discussion, duplicates

[I installed lubuntu desktop thru the terminal but my laptop reboots still as ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1152234/655715) was marked as duplicate of [Using multiple desktop environments](https://askubuntu.com/q/491044/655715)

Compare the questions and the answers.

In the first one, the OP has already installed a secondary desktop and is confused by how that works vs how he expected that to work. Vanadium does a good job at explaining how he can switch desktops.

In the other question the OP clearly shows he understands the concept of a DE and how it works. He is asking if problems could affect his current working DE. And the answer there addresses precisely that.

The questions are phrased **very** differently and the answers are both specific to their questions.

Perhaps this is a better duplicate: [Switching window manager/desktop environments?](https://askubuntu.com/q/162516/655715)

What to do?

Personally I'd like if Vanadium's answer could be accepted somehow.

I don't know how vote to reopen or if I need some amount of rep.

Answer (score 2):

To me it seems to be a fairly valid duplicate.

In the closed question, nothing about selecting desktop environments is indicated; it only say that OP has a problem with the boot logos showing incorrectly. If this is the main problem, it should be made more explicit.

If the question is about how to select the DE to use on login, they should ask that question, not a question about boot logos.

As it stands I can't really see any reason to reopen. It may not be a perfect duplicate, and it may be as valid to close it as *unclear what you're asking*, but the end result to the user would probably not be a lot better by closing as unclear. The user asking the question would have to refine it to get an answerable question.

As for accepting the answer, only the person asking the question can accept an answer. As for casting re-open vote, [that requires 3000 rep](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/close-questions). Any user with 3000 reputation or above can cast close and re-open votes.

Comment: The real question, not the title, for the second link is "Can I install extra desktop environments without affecting my current environment?". That has nothing to do with what OP is asking about.

Comment: Maybe not, and maybe *unclear what you're asking* would be a better close reason. I still don't see the close reason as totally unreasonable, given that it's rather unclear.

Comment: A dupe has this text attached: "This question already has an answer here:". This is false. That dupe target doesn't have an answer for his question. At least it should be assigned the right dupe target.

Comment: As the poster has not shown any more interest in the question, and not clarified it more, what can we do? Sure, we can spend time reopening and closing with a new reason, but realistically speaking that will not really help?

Comment: It could help others reach the right answers.

Answer (score 1):

I *added* [your suggested post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162516/switching-window-manager-desktop-environments) to the list of duplicate targets for now, although I don't really feel that either fits 100%.

As vidarlo already expressed in their answer here, the original question is really quite unclear, and it might also potentially get removed completely in the future. We will see.